# Can a G Suite admin set mail delegation for someone else?

Tags: gmail, account-management, g-suite-administrator

After you [turn mail delegation in G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7223765), the help page refers you to the regular free Gmail support in order to actually use this setting. That is, it requires, let's say secretaries - to grant access to their boss into the main office mailbox. Is there a way for a G Suite Admin to step in and directly give that access to the boss without having the secretary do it?

It's not unlike [Can the superadmin account manage other users drive folders and files?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125793/can-the-superadmin-account-manage-other-users-drive-folders-and-files/125847) but I'm asking if it can be done through the G Suite - and specifically Gmail - UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it can only be done via programming.

If you install the https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM command line package, then you can use https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/ExamplesEmailSettings#creating-a-delegate.

It basically uses https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates using a service account that has been delegated (no pun intended) a domain-wide authority.

If someone finds an easier way, I'll modify the answer.